How to send sensitive data via redirect URL to Vue router without sending in URL?In header or in cookie?
Python flask
@app.route('/redirect')
def redirect_example():
    # Assuming you have a variable 'param_value' containing the value you want to pass
    
    # Constructing the URL to redirect
    vue_route = 'http://localhost:8080/login?sid=abc'

    # Create a response object
    response = make_response(redirect(vue_route))
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

The flask app redirect to login route in vue with sid as paramters, which is read through this.$route.query.sid;
Vue.js
export default {
  created() {},
  mounted() {
    this.checkLogin();
    var self = this;
    if (!this.$route.query.sid) {
      //redirec to login_app2
      window.location.href = this.getPath("/login_app");
      return;
    }
    self.storeState.sessionId = this.$route.query.sid;
    localStorage.setItem("sessionId", self.storeState.sessionId);
    self.$router.push({ path: "/" });
    self.$parent.getUserData();
  },

I do not want to send sid in as query parameter or in URL? Is there any other way? May be through header or cookies?

Sensitive data as in? If it's sensitive and you do not want it to be shown, then you should not send it to the frontend in the first place. Just send the result that is safe.
